# ALL Extension Method is not returning expected values with more than Two Properties

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, extension-methods

I will try my best to explain what I am encountering. Basically I have two lists.

Now what I am trying to do is select all values which does not exist on the other list. But the problem is that it always return 0 values if I am using the `All` extension method and selecting more than **two** properties.

Here is my code:

**First List**:

```
IList<Person> lstOne = new List<Person>();
        lstOne.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 1, 
                IDSecond = 2,
                IDThird = 2
            });
        lstOne.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 2, 
                IDSecond = 3,
                IDThird = 2
            });
```

**Second List:**

```
        IList<Person> lstFinal = new List<Person>();
        lstFinal.Add(new Person()
        {
            ID = 1,
            IDSecond = 2,
            IDThird = 2
        });
        lstFinal.Add(new Person()
        {
            ID = 3,
            IDSecond = 4,
            IDThird = 2
        });
        lstFinal.Add(new Person()
        {
            ID = 4,
            IDSecond = 5,
            IDThird = 2
        });
```

Now if I want to select second list that doesn't exist on first list, I usually do this:

```
var resultOne = lstFinal.Where(c => lstOne
.All(x => x.ID != c.ID && x.IDSecond != c.IDSecond)).ToList();
```

This works pretty fine, the results will be two values:

```
ID: 3 and ID: 4
```

It works fine if I select one or two properties. BUT if I add additional property which I needed on my project, the results is always zero:

```
var resultOne = lstFinal.Where(c => lstOne
.All(x => x.ID != c.ID && x.IDSecond != c.IDSecond && x.IDThird != c.IDThird)).ToList();
```

My question is should be this code:

```
var resultOne = lstFinal.Where(c => lstOne
.All(x => x.ID != c.ID && x.IDSecond != c.IDSecond && x.IDThird != c.IDThird)).ToList();
```

Returns two values instead of none? I am expecting it to return this, but it return 0 values:

```
ID: 3 and ID: 4
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. First of all, why not use `Enumerable.Except()` when you want to exclude members of a list? Second, when you use `All()` you require the condition to be true for _all_ members of the source. The condition you wrote requires _all_ of the properties to be non-equal, so even if the object isn't the same, it could wind up making `All()` return false, because one of the property values matches. Please explain why you think the code you have now should work.

Comment: I understand. But should be this code: var resultOne = lstFinal.Where(c => lstOne
.All(x => x.ID != c.ID && x.IDSecond != c.IDSecond && x.IDThird != c.IDThird)).ToList(); returns two values? Instead of none?

Comment: In the data you have, the `IDThird` value is `2` for all of the original list. It's also `2` for all of the exclusion list. Which means that for every element in the original list, your call to `All()` will find that the comparison for `IDThird` fails (i.e. the value of `x.IDThird != c.IDThird` is `false`, since the values are equal). Since that expression evaluates to `false`, so does the entire predicate for `All()`, and since it's `false` for all elements of the original list, you get no elements in the result.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense, how will I do it with Except instead? Or I mean how will do it that matches those first list, and return only that don't have exact match. My expected result should be ID: 3 and ID: 4 for second list.

Comment: _"how will I do it with Except instead"_ -- see [Enumerable.Except<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll need to write an `IEqualityComparer<T>` so you can customize the equality comparison (assuming your `Person` class doesn't already implement e.g. `IEquatable<Person>` or override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerable has defined some functions that do this for you, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel

Check this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Compare : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return x.ID == y.ID && x.IDSecond == y.IDSecond;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class FullCompare : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return x.ID == y.ID && x.IDSecond == y.IDSecond && x.IDThird == y.IDThird;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int IDSecond { get; set; }
        public int IDThird { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<Person> lstOne = new List<Person>();
            lstOne.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 1,
                IDSecond = 2,
                IDThird = 2
            });
            lstOne.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 2,
                IDSecond = 3,
                IDThird = 2
            });

            IList<Person> lstFinal = new List<Person>();
            lstFinal.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 1,
                IDSecond = 2,
                IDThird = 2
            });
            lstFinal.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 3,
                IDSecond = 4,
                IDThird = 2
            });
            lstFinal.Add(new Person()
            {
                ID = 4,
                IDSecond = 5,
                IDThird = 2
            });


            var a = lstFinal.Except(lstOne, new Compare());
            var b = lstFinal.Except(lstOne, new FullCompare());
            a.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.ID));
            b.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.ID));

            Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```